# Dictionary Containing list data, filter based on value in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have test data which is gathered based on multiple inputs, and results in a single output.  I'm currently storing this data in a dictionary whose keys are my parameter/ results labels, and whose values are the test conditions and results.  I would like to be able to filter the data so I can generate plots based on isolated conditions.

In my example below, my test conditions would be 'a' and 'b', and the result of the experiment would be 'c'.  I want to filter my data so I get a dictionary with the same key, value structure and only my filtered results.  However my current dictionary comprehension returns an empty dictionary.  Any advice to get the desired result?

Current Code:

```
data = {'a': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], 'b': [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20], 'c': [1.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.3, 2.9, 3.4]}
filtered_data = {k:v for k,v in data.iteritems() if v in data['b'] >= 20}
```

Desired Result:

```
{'a': [0, 1, 2], 'b': [20, 20, 20], 'c': [2.3, 2.9, 3.4]}
```

Current Result:

```
{}
```

Also, is this dictionary of lists a good schema to store data of this type, given that I'm going to want to filter the results, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: @SilentMonk, no, it looks to me like he wants to keep items in `a` and `c` where the corresponding item in `b` is `>= 20`

Comment: you're condition >= 20 means that first the key 'a' will never have values in it nor 'c' because there are no values in that list that meet your condition

Comment: @IanMcLaird, got it. So I removed the comment. But you had already replied. Sorry.

Comment: @IanMcLaird, correct, I'm just interested in filtering based on value in the list, not based on position.

Comment: @reticentroot, I'm interested in attaining values from all lists which have the same index as the values in 'b' which are >=20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this:

```
k:[v[i] for i,x in enumerate(v) if data['b'][i] >= 20] for k,v in data.items()}
```

**Desired Result:**

```
{'a': [0, 1, 2], 'c': [2.3, 2.9, 3.4], 'b': [20, 20, 20]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the data I want is not necessarily limited to the last three values in 'b'.  For instance, I could want to filter and attain all values where 'a' = 1.

Comment: That does, this seems to be the best solution which doesn't use pandas.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the pandas module for this type of work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[df["b"] >= 20]
print(df)
```

It appears like this will give you what you want.  You are using the dictionary key to represent the column name and the values are just rows in a given column, so it is amenable to using a dataframe.

Result:

```
   a   b    c
3  0  20  2.3
4  1  20  2.9
5  2  20  3.4
```

Comment: If you would like to reset the row index add the following below the filter:
`df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: I've not used Pandas before, I'll look into this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are all of the dictionary value lists in matching orders?  If so, you could just look at whichever list you want to filter by, say `'b'` in this case, find the values you want, and then either use those indices or the same slice on the other values in the dictionary.

For example:

```
matching_indices = []
for i in data['b']:
    if data['b'][i] >= 20:
        matching_indices.append(i)
new_dict = {}
for key in data:
    for item in matching_indices:
        new_dict[key] = data[key][item]
```

You could probably figure a dictionary comprehension for it if you wanted.  Hopefully this is clear.

Comment: yes all my values are in order.  This is the route I would take if I were working in MATLAB (my native language), but I was attempting to work with comprehensions since they seem more efficient and pythonic.  If I cannot get that to work, I will go back to iterating in loops.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can change this into a method which would give it more flexibility. Your current logic means that dataset a and c are neglected because there are no values greater than or equal to 20:

```
data = {'a': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], 'b': [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20], 'c': [1.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.3, 2.9, 3.4]}
filter_vals = ['a', 'b']
new_d = {}
for k, v in data.iteritems():
  if k in filter_vals:
    new_d[k] = [i for i in v if i >= 20]

print new_d
```

Now i'm not a big fan if many if statements, but something like this is straight forward and can be called many times

```
def my_filter(operator, condition, filter_vals, my_dict):
  new_d = {}
  for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
    if k in filter_vals:
      if operator == '>':
        new_d[k] = [i for i in v if i > condition]
      elif operator == '<':
        new_d[k] = [i for i in v if i < condition]
      elif operator == '<=':
        new_d[k] = [i for i in v if i <= condition]
      elif operator == '>=':
        new_d[k] = [i for i in v if i >= condition]
  return new_d
```

Comment: Thanks @reticentroot, same comment from coralv's answer: This is the route I would take if I were working in MATLAB (my native language), but I was attempting to work with comprehensions since they seem more efficient and pythonic. If I cannot get that to work, I will go back to iterating in loops.

Comment: Then pandas is probably your best bet as shown by @Michael Lampe

Answer (score 0):

**I agree with the pandas approach above.**

If for some reason you hate pandas or are an old school computer scientist, tuples are a good way to tore relational data.  In your example, the a, b, and c lists are columns rather than rows.  For tuples, you would want to store the rows as:

```
data = {'a':(0,10,1.3),'b':(1,10,1.9),'c':(2,10,2.3),'d':(0,20,2.3),'e':(1,20,2.9),'f':(2,20,3.4)}
```

where the tuples are stored in the (condition1, condition2, outcome) format you described and you can call a single test or filter a set as you describe.  From there you can get a filtered set of results as follows:

```
filtered_data = {k:v for k,v in data.iteritems() if v[1]>=20}
```

which returns:

```
{'d': (0, 20, 2.3), 'e': (1, 20, 2.9), 'f': (2, 20, 3.4)}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  If I go this route (using rows instead of columns) then I lose my column header (dict key), so I could just use a list of lists and filter in the manner you suggest.  This is an option, but I was hoping to retain my column headings for data transfer/ self labeling.